# Database isn't generated from model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to generate a database from a model. I believe I've setup everything I can find in other questions/walktroughs, but my database doesn't seem to be generated.

Context:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext {
    public DatabaseContext()
        : base("Name=DatabaseContext") {
    }

    public DbSet<Show> Shows { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ShowMap());
    }
}
```

Mapping:

```
public class ShowMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Show> {
    public ShowMap() {
        ToTable("Shows");

        // Key
        // Properties
    }
}
```

Initializer:

```
public class DatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DatabaseContext> {
    private List<Show> _shows = new List<Show>();

    protected override void Seed(DatabaseContext context) {
        LoadShows();
        _shows.ForEach(s => context.Shows.Add(s));
    }

    private void LoadShows() {
        // Creating models
    }
}
```

Global.asax:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DatabaseInitializer());
```

Web.config:

```
<add name="DatabaseContext" connectionString="Data Source=JEROEN-DESKTOP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=NoName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I have manually created the schema 'NoName' without adding tables. Executing my program goes without problems, but no table is generated. When I look at the connections in the VS SQL server object explorer I can see both localdb and SQLEXPRESS don't contain any relevant tables.

Another thing to note: I have added EntityFramework to my project using nuget, but when I rightclick on any file/folder, I don't see EntityFramework in the context menu. Could this be the issue? I've removed and added EF to the project, but it's still not showing up. There's an 'EntityFramework' entry in my References folder though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start looking at a few things, permissions being one. Make sure the delegating caller can actually create on this database. Also validate that EF is access the database during debugging `: base("name=DatabaseContext")`. If you can access the database, IntelliTrace will give you the out put statements it is creating.

Also, I would validate migrations is enabled. Using Nuget Package Manager Console run, Enable-Migrations.The full tutorial is [Building an Initial Model & Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx)

Comment: I hadn't got migrations enabled. While enabling, I've received a few error messages concerning my connection string. Creating a new user, using a modified connection string and granting him the needed permissions removed the errors and migrations is now enabled. This didn't solve the problem though. How exactly would I go about finding whether or not EF is accessing the database? I've put a breakpoint at the `:base()` of DatabaseContext as you suggested and the problem executes without halting. Do I have to explicitly create a new instance of DatabaseContext somewhere?

Comment: What app pool is the site running under? That app pool needs permission on it, you can always grant dbo owner and then tune permissions down as needed.

Comment: It's just local on my machine as a hobby project. It can have all the permissions available. Just to be sure: is this the correct connectionstring to connect to a SQL Express server?

`<add name="DatabaseContext" connectionString="Server=JEROEN-DESKTOP\SQLEXPRESS;Database=NoName;User Id=Jeroen;Password=newpass;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Comment: Yes that looks fine, standard format. Do you have mixed mode authentication enabled?

Comment: Yes, SQL Server and Windows Authentication are both allowed.

Comment: Solved! I had to enable Automatic migrations first (`Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName NoName.Models.Data.DatabaseContext -EnableAutomaticMigrations -Force`) and update the database afterwards (`Update-Database`). Now the tables are appearing as they should!